# Too much space occupied by several filesystems

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, disk-usage, tmpfs

Here is the output of the `df -h` command on my recently set up `Ubuntu 16.04.01`

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           790M  9,8M  780M   2% /run
/dev/sdb5       213G   75G  128G  38% /
tmpfs           3,9G  152M  3,8G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       459G  3,9G  432G   1% /mag
tmpfs           790M  108K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
```

`/dev/sdb5` is a SSD of 240G and `/dev/sda1` a HDD of 500G.

My questions is what are the following filesystems that eat up so much space and if there is a way to reclaim that space (if it is not critical for the system of course!).

`udev` (on `/dev`) (3.9G)

`tmpfs` (on `/dev/shm`) (3.9G)

`tmpfs` (on `/sys/fs/cgroup`) (3.9G)

My main problem is that apparently that space has been deprived from the SSD and not the HDD.

Comment: What make you think that your SSD has been "deprived" from space. According to your 'df' -h' command / on /dev/sdb5 has 128 GB of 213 GB free, and /mag on /dev/sda1 has 432 GB of 495 GB free. Tmpfs are in-memory-filesystems and dont take up space on your disks.

Comment: I assumed that because `Size` value of SSD is 213G while the disk is supposed to have a capacity of 240G. On the other hand I see the case is more or less the same for the HDD ...

Comment: Take a look at the disk in 'gparted' to see wat other partitions that might be.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a reading comprehension problem - `/dev` and `/sys/fs/cgroup` have **zero** space used, and `/dev/shm` has 152 MB used - even if they were on disk, that's peanuts.

Comment: @muru does this mean the space for those fs under `Size` is free for use?

Comment: The space under `Avail` (i.e., Available) is free for use

Answer (score 1):

These special filesystems are RAM mounted, so the 3.9 GB space shown is  the available RAM space.